# Create a new user when using facebook authentication - Django

Tags: django, django-authentication, python-social-auth

I am following a book to learn Django, "Django by Example". At this moment I am learning how to use facebook authentication system using the python-social-auth package.

Before using the facebook login each user should register on the website, where I use the following function, where you can see it creates a new_user and a profile linked to this new_user:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if  user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:
            print (user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

I am wondering what I should do to create a new user when someone login with facebook, and at the same time creating a profile linked to this user.